# hide and show error with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 selects two hidden and one visible when I select the first option appears when you press one and the other the second option. All this in a table and use jquery to create a new row button in manipulacion.js file a counter and I have added it to the id of each select to not just call. the error is when I create a new row and not change me, I open the console and do not check any error.
here I attached my codes in html and. js can copy it for them to discover that I'm wrong.

code html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="manipulacion.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#estado").change(function () {
            if ($("#estado").val() == 2) {
                $("#sino").show();
                $("#sexo").hide();            
            }
            if ($("#estado").val() == 3) {
                $("#sino").hide();
                $("#sexo").show();
            }
            });
            });
    </script>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="estado">
    <option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option>
    <option value="2">Laboratorio</option>
    <option value="3">Datos Generales</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- //laboratorio -->
    <select name="sino" id="sino"style="display:none">
    <option value="1">Si </option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <!-- //datos generales -->
    <select name="sexo" id="sexo"  style="display:none">
    <option value="1">Masculino </option>
    <option value="2">Femenino</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code manipulacion.js

```
//manipulacion 
var contLin=1
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#estado"+contLin).change(function () {      
            if ($("#estado"+contLin).val() == 2) {
                $("#sino"+contLin).show();
                $("#sexo"+contLin).hide();       
            }
            if ($("#estado"+contLin).val() == 3) {
                $("#sino"+contLin).hide();
                $("#sexo"+contLin).show();
            }
}           );



});


$(document).ready(function(){
    //evento que se dispara al hacer clic en el boton para agregar una nueva fila
    $(document).on('click','.clsAgregarFila',function(){
        //almacenamos en una variable todo el contenido de la nueva fila que deseamos
        //agregar. pueden incluirse id's, nombres y cualquier tag... sigue siendo html

        var strNueva_Fila='<tr>'+
'<td><select id="estado'+contLin+'"><option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option><option value="2">Laboratorio</option><option value="3">Datos Generales</option></select></td>' +
'<td><select name="sino'+contLin+'" id="sino"style="display:none"><option value="1">Si </option><option value="2">No</option></select></td>'+
'<td> <select name="sexo'+contLin+'" id="sexo"  style="display:none"><option value="1">Masculino </option><option value="2">Femenino</option></select><td>'+
'<td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"><input type="button" value="-" class="clsEliminarFila"></td>'+
'</tr>';

contLin++;

        var objTabla=$(this).parents().get(3);


        $(objTabla).find('tbody').append(strNueva_Fila);


        if(!$(objTabla).find('tbody').is(':visible')){

            $(objTabla).find('caption').click();
        }
    });


    $(document).on('click','.clsEliminarFila',function(){

        var objCuerpo=$(this).parents().get(2);
            if($(objCuerpo).find('tr').length==1){
                if(!confirm('Esta es el única fila de la lista ¿Desea eliminarla?')){
                    return;
                }
            }


        var objFila=$(this).parents().get(1);

            $(objFila).remove();
    });



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused because `$("#estado"+contLin).change(function () {` is binding the function to the element `#estado1` (since `contLin=1` initially), but the JavaScript is executed when the document is ready and that element `#estado1` does not exist.

One quick way to fix this is to move the change event function into `$(document).on('click','.clsAgregarFila',function(){` body so that a new change function is bound to the new `#estadoX` when the table row is being appended. However this is *very* inefficient and I would advise using event delegation, which you are actually already using for the click handler functions on `.clsAgregarFila` and `.clsEliminarFila`.

Event delegation works by binding the handler function to a parent or ancestor DOM element which *already exists*. The event is then handled on that element and delegated down (by way of the CSS selector you specify) onto the target element.

For example `$(document).on('click','.clsAgregarFila',function(){` means that the handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element (`document`), but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector (all elements with `class="clsAgregarFila"`) - see [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

So you *could* just use the following, which uses the CSS attribute selector to match all `<select>` elements that **start with** `id="estado"`. But there is a small problem - it will not work like this…

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[id^=estado]', function () {
    if ($("#estado"+contLin).val() == 2) {
        $("#sino"+contLin).show();
        $("#sexo"+contLin).hide();       
    }
    if ($("#estado"+contLin).val() == 3) {
        $("#sino"+contLin).hide();
        $("#sexo"+contLin).show();
    }
});
```

…since `contLin == 2` as it is a global variable! What we really want is to find the `<select>`s on the *current row*. So the following amended function should work and even better can replace *both* of your functions, removing code duplication :-)

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select[id^=estado]', function () {
      var estadoValue = parseInt(this.value);
      var rowSelects = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').slice(1);

      $(rowSelects[0]).toggle(estadoValue === 2);
      $(rowSelects[1]).toggle(estadoValue === 3);
});
```

However, taking this approach further, your code could be rewritten like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RprF/). I have removed the HTML string and used [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to add a row, simplified removing a row, chained the event handling and removed the element counter - replacing with classes instead.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  var $tbody = $('tbody');
  var strNueva_Fila = $tbody.find('tr:first');

  $('tbody').on('change', 'select.estado', function() {
      var estadoValue = parseInt(this.value);
      var rowSelects = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').slice(1);

      $(rowSelects[0]).toggle(estadoValue === 2);
      $(rowSelects[1]).toggle(estadoValue === 3);
  }).on('click', 'input', function() {
      if (this.className === 'clsAgregarFila') {
        $tbody.append(strNueva_Fila.clone());
      } else if (this.className === 'clsEliminarFila') {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      }

      buttonsToggle();
  });

  function buttonsToggle() {
    var $addButtons = $tbody.find('.clsAgregarFila');
    var $removeButtons = $tbody.find('.clsEliminarFila');

    // hide all
    $addButtons.hide();
    $removeButtons.hide();

    // show "-" button on all but first row
    $removeButtons.slice(0).show();

    // but hide "-" if there is only 1 row
    if ($removeButtons.length === 1) {
      $removeButtons.hide();
    }

    // show "+" button on last row only
    $addButtons.slice(-1).show();
  }
});
```

***HTML*** (Note: I have added the "-" `<input>` and the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements).

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <select id="estado" class="estado">
      <option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option>
      <option value="2">Laboratorio</option>
      <option value="3">Datos Generales</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <!-- //laboratorio -->
      <select name="sino" class="sino" id="sino" style="display:none">
      <option value="1">Si </option>
      <option value="2">No</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <!-- //datos generales -->
      <select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="sexo" style="display:none">
      <option value="1">Masculino </option>
      <option value="2">Femenino</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"/><input type="button" value="-" class="clsEliminarFila" style="display:none"/></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Hope this helps :-)